# How to set Vim NERDTree to prevent show .git folders and files?

Tags: git, vim, nerdtree

I make visible all hidden files and folders, also, `.git` folders and files (`.git`, `.gitignore` and etc.)

In a project tree when using `NERDTree` in Vim, I wanted to manage to show all other hidden files except `.git` folder and its subfolders and files.

How I can do it?

Comment: Did you try 'I' in NERDTree window?

Comment: thanks - I just found solution - in my .vimrc I had ignored .git files on nerdtree with let NERDTreeIgnore=["\.git"].quick tip - I found that you can toggle hidden files in nerd tree with shift+i

Comment: Dear @carousel, I leave an upvote for your great question, it is very useful to migrate from modern IDEs to Vim. also I make a large edit on your question and additionally add a complete answer for future users.

Answer (score 16):

Press `Shift+I` when in the NerdTree window

Answer (score 13):

It worked for me. Did you try the following options ?

```
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
```

Maybe you are not at the root of your git repo and that is why you don't see any `.git* files/dirs`

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the question post wants to show all hidden files and folders but *ignore* some files or folders like `.git` folder. for this setting:

1. We should show all hidden files and folders by default, so open the `.vimrc` file and at the end of file insert the following command:

```
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
```

2. We should ignore some files or folders like other IDEs, so open the `.vimrc` file again and the end of file insert the following command too:

```
let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.git$']
```

**Hint**: recently I migrated from `VSCode` and `WebStorm` to `Vim` so on the second step I ignore some other files and folders, I mean:

```
let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.git$', '\.idea$', '\.vscode$', '\.history$']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following to your `.vimrc` file:

```sh
let NERDTreeIgnore=[".git"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
let g:NERDTreeIgnore = ['\.git$']
```

Note that it must start with " \ " and end with "$". This works for Windows, Linux and MacOs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in lua config files: (for nvim users)

```lua
filters = {
   dotfiles = false,
   custom = {"^\\.git"},
},
```